# headers are not being set into AXIOS post request

Tags: reactjs, http, redux, cors, axios

I am working on react-redux App. When i am making Api Post request to Rest Api(on CORS). Headers are not being set. But when i try this in postman it work perfectly.

this is the code: 
I want to send TOKEN(for testing).

```
post: (endPoint, data) => {
        return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${apiPath}/${endPoint}`,
            data: data,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'TOKEN': 1111}
        }).then((res) =>{
            return res;
        })
    }
```

Comment: to my knowledge, this should work fine. may be because of different quotes?

Comment: This is the header, that i got. There is not TOKEN. 
 Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:196
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:3001
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3001/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36

Comment: I am making request on different domain(CORS request). know that there something wrong with headers or api call.

Comment: That 'application/json' content-type and the 'TOKEN' header will both cause the browser to send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before sending the POST your code is trying to send. If that OPTIONS preflight fails then the browser won’t send the POST. So you want to check your browser devtools console to see what messages the browser is logging and what the result of the OPTIONS preflight is

Comment: @sideshowbarker Both requests 'POST' and 'OPTIONS'  works without errror. It just i am not getting header(TOKEN) in any request header.

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem - did you find out what the issue was?